# How to make car deform when hits and keeps this form

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

In my car game I would like to make the metal bend, when it hits a wall. I think of soft body or cloth simulation. How can I achieve that the metal stays solid, but deforms when it hits and keeps this form, like metal? But what I did results in the material being stuck in the obstacle.  Thanks :)

This are the settings:
[image]
[image]

Plastic is high, so it keeps the deformation
Pull and push are low, because they must stretch and be pushed together. I looked at the tutorial of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofIi4ddHGW0

Comment: Hi Faceb :) Your question is to broad and shows no effort, please add what you have tried and what **exactly** do you want to achieve.

Comment: Uhhhhh, you pretty much ask for a Rigid Body Simulation beyond the yield strength of a material.. that isn't even a "solved" problem in material science afaik, so if you find a plugin for it, PM me. Until then I think you have to find a workaround. Maybe substitute the original with predefined damaged objects when they match close enough